# Which schedulers for rails 3.1 or above can stay on all the time on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, rufus-scheduler

We are looking for a scheduler which can stay on all the time for our rails 3.1 app on ubuntu 12.04 server. Currently we are using rufus scheduler which could be killed by Passenger by accident and can not stay on all the time. There are quite a few of schedulers available out there. We are looking for a simple and easy to use one for our rails app. The primary purpose of the scheduler is to fire off periodically to check the session timestamp and reset if necessary.  Any recommendation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at clockwork?

https://rubygems.org/gems/clockwork

Answer (score 0):

For rufus-scheduler vs Passenger, you might want to look at [Debugging Rufus scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108719/debugging-rufus-scheduler/18156180#18156180)

Else if you don't want to tune your Passenger, go the crond way and use Whenever: https://github.com/javan/whenever